# Vue.js client-side hydration works in development but fails in production

Tags: vue.js, vue-ssr

I decided to build my own Vue SSR [template](https://github.com/iloginow/vue-base-template) that I could use for my projects. It's partially based on [this example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/). Everything was fine and worked as expected. And it still does on the dev-server) But when I'd built the app for production I suddenly discovered that it was totally dead. I got no errors, no warnings, no other signs that could point out the direction where I should search for the answers whatsoever... And it's just blowing my mind!

The app works perfectly on dev-server but in production, it appears to be totally dead as client-side hydration somehow fails.

I'm not sure what it is really... Or maybe I'm just stupid enough to miss something very simple here. I just don't know. I spent so much time trying to solve this... But found nothing, and I feel pretty helpless. So any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It was so simple that it’s actually very funny.

That’s what will happen if you accidentally define a wrong entry point for your client bundle in webpack config.

So be aware!
Hopefully, it would save some time for someone)